# How do I convert date and time from the jPlaton format to the international standard date and time notation?

Tags: date, time, format

I am using the jPlaton platform and I have a PlatonScript record that contains a date and a time field.

The date field is a integer like 20140526.
I want to convert it to a YYYY-MM-DD string. That it: 20140526 --> "2014-05-26"

The time field is a integer like 90903417.
I want to convert it to an HH:mm:ss string. That it: 90903417 --> "09:09:03"

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic functions you need are:

- ASDATE (for integer to string transformation)

  example: `#s_dateFromInteger# = (ASDATE:YYYY-MM-DD) #s_integerDate#`
- ASTIME (for long to string transformation)

  example: `#s_timeFromLong# = (ASTIME:HH:mm:ss) #s_longTime#`

In these examples `#s_dateFromInteger#` and `#s_timeFromLong#` are the Strings you require.

`s_integerDate` is the classic integer date representation used by jPlaton (yyyyddmm).

`s_longTime` is the classic long time representation used by the platform (hhmmssSSS)

Don't forget that the date and time patterns used by Platonscript are the usual JAVA patterns, since Platonscript interpreter returns pure JAVA